# ggpubr: sort by group but with different sorting order (asc, desc)

Tags: r, sorting, grouping, ggpubr

I want to sort a data by group and then for each group, sort by different orders (ascending, none, descending), but it seems that `ggpubr`'s `sort.val` argument only takes value of length 1. I am wondering what alternative way I can do to have the output achieve desired result without extensive modiciation?

I'll use the `mtcars` data as an illustrative example. The data is sorted by `cyl` group (3 groups) and rendered in `asc` order, is it possible to assign the three groups with different sorting orders? Say, for example, "asc", "none", "desc"? (I've tried `c("asc", "none", "desc")`, but it didn't work).

Below is my minimal working example.

```css
# Require the package
library(ggpubr)


data("mtcars")
dfm <- mtcars
# Convert the cyl variable to a factor
dfm$cyl <- as.factor(dfm$cyl)
# Add the name colums
dfm$name <- rownames(dfm)
# Inspect the data
head(dfm[, c("name", "wt", "mpg", "cyl")])

# Sort by group and by ascending order

ggbarplot(dfm, x = "name", y = "mpg",
          fill = "cyl",       # change fill color by cyl
         color = "white", # Set bar border colors to white
          palette = "jco",  # jco journal color palett. 
          sort.val = "asc",  # Sort the value in dscending order 
          sort.by.groups = TRUE, # Sort inside each group
          x.text.angle = 90 # Rotate vertically x axis texts
          )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to do within `ggbarplot` function of `ggpubr` but here is one way by manipulating factor levels.

We create a dataframe (`order_data`) which has the order in which we want the data to be sorted for each group. Here, I use the convention 1 as ascending order, 0 as no order and -1 as descending order.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggpubr)

order_data <- data.frame(cyl = factor(c(4, 6, 8)), order = c(1, 0, -1))
order_data

#  cyl order
#1   4     1
#2   6     0
#3   8    -1
```

Multiply the `order` value with `mpg` and `arrange` the data, turn the name values as factor based on their occurrence and plot.

```
dfm %>%
  left_join(order_data, by = 'cyl') %>%
  arrange(cyl, mpg * order) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, name)) %>%
  ggbarplot(x = "name", y = "mpg",
          fill = "cyl",       # change fill color by cyl
          color = "white", # Set bar border colors to white
          palette = "jco",  # jco journal color palett. 
          x.text.angle = 90 # Rotate vertically x axis texts
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way with first data manipulation:

1. rownames to first column with `rownames_to_column`
2. `cyl` to factor
3. after grouping `sort` within the groups with and `ifelse` statement
4. and important `arrange` by `cyl`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

dfm <- mtcars %>% 
    rownames_to_column("name") %>% 
    mutate(cyl = as_factor(cyl)) %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    mutate(mpg=ifelse(cyl==4, sort(mpg), mpg),
           mpg=ifelse(cyl==8, sort(mpg, decreasing = TRUE), mpg)
    ) %>% 
    arrange(cyl)

# plot
ggbarplot(dfm, x = "name", y = "mpg",
          fill = "cyl",       # change fill color by cyl
          color = "white", # Set bar border colors to white
          palette = "jco",  # jco journal color palett.  
          x.text.angle = 90 # Rotate vertically x axis texts
)
```

[image]